# How do I store only unique values in array in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, ubuntu

I am looking for a way to extract digits from the files with different names with similar digits and store only unique values in array instead of duplicates. For example I have file names like, `12-fil1.txt`, `12-file2.txt`, `24-file1.txt`, `24-file2.txt`. So my array will have values `array=(12, 24)`. I apologize if this is a dumb question but I am new to bash so I am having hard time figuring out the way to do this.

Comment: Pipe the output of extracting the numbers from the filenames to `sort -u`, and store that into the array.

Comment: You mean first I should store all the values in an array and then use `sort -u` to get only unique values from array?

Comment: No, you never store all the values. You have a loop like `array=($(for name in *.txt; do echo <something that extracts the number prefix from name>; done | sort -u))`

Answer (score 1):

Easily done with Associative arrays

```
declare -A array

for file in *.txt; { array[${file%-*}]=''; }
echo ${!array[@]}
```

Update. If `declare -A array` removed then we've got simple indexed array witch in this case is also works, because we need to store only numbers, but we store them as indexes not as data.

Comment: Just to note, `for x in y; { ... }` is an undocumented shortcut for `for x in y; do ...; done`. I would stick with the documented form, as there's no guarantee that the shortcut will always be supported.

Comment: Thanks for this! Though the output gives characters as well instead of only numbers. But if remove the `declare -A array`, I will get only numbers which is exactly what I want. Any idea why this happens?

Comment: @JayS, indeed, updated my answer.

Answer (score 0):

you can make use of associative arrays

```
declare -A chk
declare -a uniques
while read -r line; do
  #do something with line or use multiple variables instead of line
  v="$(cut -d " " -f 1 <<< $line)"
  [[ ${chk[$v]} ]] || uniques+=("$v")
  chk[$v]=1
done < file.txt
```